# 正規表現リテラルに変数を使用する方法はありますか？

Tags: javascript, 正規表現

RegExpを利用して、正規表現オブジェクトを変数strから生成する以下の形式

```
let regexp = new RegExp(str + '(.*?)', 'gmi');
```

を正規表現リテラルで記載することはできますでしょうか？

以下のコード程度しか思いつかず、これでは正規表現オブジェクトにはなりませんでした

```
let regexp = '/' + str + '(.*?)'  + '/gmi';
```

お知恵を拝借できれば幸いです。

Comment: ご質問にあるような書き方を尊重するのであれば、[eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)が使えるかもしれませんが、`RegExp`コンストラクタより優秀な方法ではありませんね……どういった理由で”リテラル”が必要なのでしょうか。`let regexp = eval('/' + str + '(.*?)'  + '/gmi');`

Answer (score 1):

下記記事をご参照ください。

[Javascript Regex: How to put a variable inside a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029109/javascript-regex-how-to-put-a-variable-inside-a-regular-expression)

Chrome 71.0で正規表現リテラルに文字列を埋め込もうとしてもできませんでした。つまり、できないということです。

```
> a
"abc"
> /${a}/
/${a}/
> `${a}`
"abc"
```

Answer (score 1):

evalで無理やりやってみればこんな感じですかね。

```
function    var_replace( s, reg, tgt ){
var repstr  = '\'' + s + '\'.replace(' + reg + ',\'' + tgt + '\')'
return  eval( repstr )
}

var str ='abcdef1234+-=';
var reg='/\\d/g'    //javascriptの文字列の仕様上、バックスラッシュは二重にしなければならない
console.log( str.replace( /\d/g, '@' ) )
console.log( str.replace( reg, '@' ) )
console.log( var_replace( str, reg, '@' ) )
```